# How can I merge differently formatted manifests into one manifest?

Tags: c#, manifest

I am looking for some tips/advice on how I could merge a number of different manifests into one manifest that captures each element of each manifest.

So say I have the following 3 manifests with the following format. As you can see some elements repeat and some are unique to the manifest. Also the manifests contain thousands of rows under each element.

Manifest 1:

```
Element1|Element2|Element4|Element5|
00000001|00000002|00000004|00000005|
```

Manifest 2:

```
Element2|Element3|Element4|Element5|
00000002|00000003|00000004|00000005|
```

Manifest 3:

```
Element1|Element3|Element4|Element6|
00000001|00000003|00000004|00000006|
```

**The final manifest I would want would look something like this:**

```
Element1|Element2|Element4|Element5|Element3|Element6|
00000001|00000002|00000004|00000005|00000003|________|
________|00000002|00000004|00000005|________|________|
00000001|________|00000004|________|00000003|00000006|
```

As you can see every field is captured from the original manifests and saved into one master manifest. If an element is not available in a particular manifest then the row is left empty.

Comment: are you referring to Application Manifest Files, which are in XML format? you're showing some random tabular data here.....

Comment: Please clarify your question, we have no idea what you're referring to with "manifest" as it looks completely unrelated to Application Manifest files.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with your terminology, making it difficult or impossible to understand what this is all about. "Manifest" is not explained, "element" probably actually should be called "column", and when you use the word "row" I think you actually mean "cell" or "element".

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure what you mean by "Manifest", and know nothing about input/output file structure or where it comes from, etc. I assumed CSV data, so here is an example for that. Hope it will help you achieve your goal.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var merger = new CsvMerger(Console.Out);
        Guid type1 = merger.RegisterType(new [] { "Element1", "Element2", "Element3" });
        Guid type2 = merger.RegisterType(new[] { "Element3", "Element5", "Element6" });
        merger.WriteHeaders();
        merger.WriteData(type1, "00000001", "00000002", "00000003");
        merger.WriteData(type2, "00000003", "00000005", "00000006");
    }
}

public class CsvMerger
{
    readonly TextWriter output;
    const string OutputSeparator = "|";
    bool canAddTypes = true;
    readonly List<string> fieldNames = new List<string>(); 
    readonly Dictionary<Guid, int[]> positionMap = new Dictionary<Guid, int[]>(); 


    public CsvMerger(TextWriter output)
    {
        this.output = output;
    }

    public Guid RegisterType(params string[] dataLayout)
    {
        if (!this.canAddTypes)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Already started writing data, cannot add more source types");
        int[] positions = new int[dataLayout.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataLayout.Length; i++)
        {
            int position = this.fieldNames.IndexOf(dataLayout[i]);
            if (position == -1)
            {
                positions[i] = this.fieldNames.Count;
                this.fieldNames.Add(dataLayout[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                positions[i] = position;
            }
        }
        Guid typeKey = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.positionMap[typeKey] = positions;
        return typeKey;
    }

    public void WriteHeaders()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(OutputSeparator, this.fieldNames));
    }

    public void WriteData(Guid type, params string[] data)
    {
        this.canAddTypes = false;
        int[] map = this.positionMap[type];
        string[] arrangedDataBuffer = new string[this.fieldNames.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            arrangedDataBuffer[map[i]] = data[i];
        }
        this.output.WriteLine(string.Join(OutputSeparator, arrangedDataBuffer));

    }
}
```